# Why regexp_matches for none matching rows work like a filter, and doesn't return?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to understand why

```
SELECT *, regexp_matches(A, 'pattern') FROM table
```

would only return rows where `A` has pattern `pattern`, even though I don't have `WHERE` clause?

What does `regexp_matches` return if there is no match? I had thought it was `null`, but if it is `null` then the query should simply return `null` for all those non matching results?

How can I build custom functions to do similar thing: when the argument fits, the corresponding rows are filtered so that I don't have to append `where`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a side effect of using Set Returning Function as scalar function. Set Returning Functions returns a table instead scalar function and usually are used in FROM clause. You can use it like scalar function (from some reasons), but with very strange side effects some times. Usually you don't would to use these function on scalar function position.

```
postgres=# select * from foo;
 a 
---
 1
 2
(2 rows)

postgres=# select a, generate_series(1,0) from foo;
 a | generate_series 
---+-----------------
(0 rows)

postgres=# select a, generate_series(1,1) from foo;
 a | generate_series 
---+-----------------
 1 |               1
 2 |               1
(2 rows)

postgres=# select a, generate_series(1,2) from foo;
 a | generate_series 
---+-----------------
 1 |               1
 1 |               2
 2 |               1
 2 |               2
(4 rows)
```

Probably you would to use a substring function with regular expression. It is scalar function:

```
postgres=# select 'Some string', substring('Ahoj29' from '^[0-9]+');
  ?column?   | substring 
-------------+-----------
 Some string | 
(1 row)

postgres=# select 'Some string', substring('Ahoj29' from '[0-9]+');
  ?column?   | substring 
-------------+-----------
 Some string | 29
(1 row)
```